# Text goes over a floated div which have negative margin

Tags: css

Is possible the text to stop or go to a new row if meets a floated div which have negative margin? Without specify width to divs or apply ellipsis?

```css
.floatedconteiner {
float: right;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #333;
margin-top: -80px;
}
```

```html
<div id ="container">
<a href="https://www.hoohle.com"><h2>This text goes over a floated div - This text goes over a floated div - This text goes over a floated div</h2></a>
<div class="floatedconteiner">My floated container<br>
<span class="myspan">2019</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using floats like this in the day and age of css 3

Answer (score 0):

Negative margin should not be present here. And the order of elements is important as well.

```css
.floatedconteiner {
float: right;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div id ="container">
  <div class="floatedconteiner">
    My floated container<br>
    <span class="myspan">2019</span>
  </div>
  <a href="https://www.hoohle.com">
    <h2>This text goes over a floated div - This text goes over a floated div - This text goes over a floated div</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, if floated div is first in HTML I know everything is OK, but on mobile devices this floated div will be first on responsive devices and I need to be the last, so after main container. And with CSS is not possible easy to move this floated div via @media only screen and (max-width: 980px) to be last.

Answer (score 0):

Give the heading a right margin equal to or greater than the width of the floated element:

```css
.floatedconteiner {
  float: right;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin-top: -80px;
}

h2 {
  margin-right: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a href="https://www.hoohle.com">
    <h2>This text goes over a floated div - This text goes over a floated div - This text goes over a floated div</h2>
  </a>
  <div class="floatedconteiner">My floated container<br>
    <span class="myspan">2019</span>
  </div>
</div>
```